# All solutions of $\frac{n}{2z} = \sum\limits_{i=1}^n \frac{1}{z-c_i}$ lie on the unit circle given that $|c_i| = 1, 1 \le i \le n.$

Tags: complex-analysis, polynomials, complex-numbers

> Prove that all solutions of $\frac{n}{2z} = \sum\limits_{i=1}^n
> \frac{1}{z-c_i}$ lie on the unit circle given that $|c_i| = 1$ for $1
> \le i \le n.$

If $n=1,$ then $z = -c_1.$ If $n=2,$ then $z = \pm \sqrt{c_1 c_2}.$ Trying to prove the statement through brute force for $n \ge 3$ quickly becomes unfeasible. I tried a proof by contradiction by assuming that $|z| < 1$ or $|z| > 1$:

$\frac{n}{2|z|} = \left|\sum\limits_{i=1}^n \frac{1}{z-z_i}\right| \le \sum\limits_{i=1}^n \frac{1}{|z-z_i|} \le \frac{n}{|1-|z||}.$ If $|z| > 1,$ this gives $-1 \le |z|,$ which we already know. If $|z| < 1,$ this gives $|z| \ge 1/3,$ which is not helpful enough. Thus, we must take into account the argument of the LHS and RHS of the original equation. But assuming that a point lies off of the unit circle does not place any constraints on its argument, so we can't get a contradiction that way either. We must somehow consider the argument and magnitude of $z$ simultaneously. How do we do this? Any approaches, hints, or ideas? What would be the motivation behind these approaches? Is there something obvious I'm missing?

Comment: Multiplying by $\prod\limits_i (z-c_i)$ RHS heavily reminds me of Lagrange polynomial. Not sure if that helps, mostly not.

Comment: I'm also not sure if it helps, but we can rewrite it as $\sum_i \frac {z + c_i} {z - c_i} = 0$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Note that
$$\begin{align}
\sum\limits_{i=1}^n
\frac{1}{z-c_i} - \frac{n}{2z} &=
\sum_{i=1}^n (\frac{1}{z-c_i} - \frac 1{2z}) \\
&=  \frac{1}{2z}\sum_{i=1}^n \frac{z+c_i}{z-c_i}\\
&= \frac{1}{2z}\sum_{i=1}^n \frac{|z|^2-z\bar{c_i}+c_i\bar z -1}{|z-c_i|^2}.
\end{align}$$

Since $-z\bar{c_i}+c_i\bar z$ has real part $0$, $\displaystyle \frac{n}{2z} = \sum\limits_{i=1}^n
\frac{1}{z-c_i}$ implies $$(|z|^2-1) \sum_{i=1}^n \frac{1}{|z-c_i|^2}=0$$
hence $|z|=1$.

Comment: What motivated you to spread $\frac{n}{2z}$ across the summation? I can see how the solution is natural once you bring that term in and simplify everything.

Comment: @Displayname At first I noticed that if $P(X) =  \prod_{i=1}^n (X-c_i)$ then the problem rewrites as $z$ root of $\frac n2 P(X) - XP' \implies |z|=1$. I couldn't see how to prove that using facts on polynomials. So instead I looked for an algebraic proof. When $n a+\sum_{i=1}^n b_i$ pops up, it's always worth trying to explore $\sum_{i=1}^n (a+b_i)$.

Comment: Funny that you should arrive at the problem $np/2 = xp',$ because I actually started from there and arrived at the form in the title before posting because having a summation instead of a product seemed like progress.